# Can I splice a main neutral in a new feed thru (meter panel) box?

Tags: wiring

I replaced an old existing meter panel with a 200 Amp feed through. The problem is I came up about 3 inches short with the neutral for the underground feed to the house. My question is: Can I add a piece of neutral with a crimp connector inside the feed-through panel?

Comment: Unless there's a connector specifically designed to handle this kind of load and this gauge of cable, and you have the tools/experience to install it properly -- and your local code approves of it -- I would have to assume not. I think the right answer is "Pull the existing neutral out and run a new one which has the needed length, or find a way to move the feedthrough the necessary three inches closer."

Comment: The feed wire up to the meter panel is generally the responsibility of the power company, you are better off asking them for possible solutions.

Comment: could you lower the meter box by a couple inches?

Answer (score 1):

The code allows you to splice service entrance conductors (230.46) 2011 code book.  But you cannot splice them in the meter can.  You have to use a weatherproof box seperate from the meter can; if installed outside, and weatherproof fittings.  The splice must be made with approved equipment.  Remember a chain is as strong as it's weakest link.  If you ever have a problem with the feed it will be thewre.  Best thing to do is re-run the line if it's economical it would be best.